# Anyone got MongoDB java driver working with Xpages?

Tags: xpages

Aynone got MongoDB driver working with Xpages? I'm getting following error on server console when MongoDB client tries to connect to its server.

```
30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread. For more detailed information, please consult
C:/domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread. For more detailed information, please consult
C:/domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM: Exception in thread "cluster-1-localhost:27017"
30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread
30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM:        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent(NotesContext.java:123)
30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM:        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:383)
30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM:        at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(ServerMonitor.java:162)
30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM:        at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(ServerMonitor.java:143)
30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM:        at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(ServerMonitor.java:120)
[12C8:00DF-590C] 30.06.2014 20:32:55   HTTP JVM:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
```

**+++ Update #1**

a) I put the required libraries into database web-inf\libs and put them on path

b) this only line causes the stacktrace above

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
```

Comment: Where did you put your code. What code did you use? Code rulez

Comment: Updated the former post ...

Comment: Your question led me to give it a try and copy all required jars into 'jvm\lib\ext' folder and it works now.  Is there a way how to keep jars as part of NSF and avoid installing them on filesystem which is ussualy not available for us on remote server?

Comment: Create a plug-in project and share on GitHub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems your issue is with access rights. If you want to add the JARs as a plugin instead of putting them in the jvm/lib/ext directory (which quickly becomes a mess) then you could wrap them in an OSGi plugin and deploy that to your server/Domino Designer.

I had the same challenges 6 months ago - and when I figured out, I wrote a blog article about how to do it (well actually two - also how to deploy). You can see the details here: http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in/

The jars are not part of the database - but you will enable them for the database (or for each database where you need it - since they will be available to all).

HTH ;-)

/John

Comment: Unbelievable, but helped me as well! )